# What is the complexity of the following problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, reductions, satisfiability, decision-problem

**Input:** $M$ is non deterministic Turing machine that always halts in $cn^k$ moves/steps, where $c$ and $k$ are constants and $n$ is the length of the input string of $M$, $w$ is any string in $\Sigma^*$ and $a$ is another string in $\Sigma^*$ where $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$.

**Output**: Does $a$ represent a valid computation of $M$ on $w$?

$a$ indeed encodes truth assignment, when the symbol $0$ encodes **false** value and the symbol $1$ encodes **true** value.

If $a$ **satisfies** $\Phi_{M,w}$, where $\Phi_{M,w}$ is the boolean formula that deterministic Turing machine can compute in polynomial time by the Cook Levin reduction that is satisfiable if and only if $M$ accepts $w$, then $a$ is indeed represents a valid computation of $M$ on $w$ since the Cook Levin reduction is **parsimonious**.

But if $a$ **falsifies** $\Phi_{M,w}$ then this is **not** necessarily true 
that $a$ represents a valid computation of $M$ on $w$, because it is possible that the given non deterministic Turing machine $M$ accepts the given string $w$ on **all** computations, paths and routes and the given truth assignment $a$ still falsifies $\Phi_{M,w}$.

So in case that $a$ falsifies $\Phi$, how do I decide whether or not $a$ represents a valid computation of $M$ on $w$?

What is the complexity of this problem?

Does exist polynomial time deterministic algorithm that decides/solves this problem or nobody doesn't know if such algorithm exist yet?

Comment: "then $a$ indeed represents a valid computation of $M$ on $w$ since the Cook Levin reduction is parsimonious" - This has nothing to do with the reduction being parsimonious, this is a result of the specific construction of the reduction. Also, you don't have to appeal to Cook-Levin to encode computations of a Turing machine, there is no real reason to talk about assignments for boolean formulas in this context. You can simply say that $a$ is a description of $M$'s tape, state and head location during some prefix of its computation.

Comment: Additionally, the input should consist of $M, w$ alone, you don't have any information about $M$'s running time from its encoding (how would you know if the machine actually runs in exponential time?). Now, the problem is trivially solvable in polynomial time by reading $a$ and checking that any configuration is reachable from its predecessor by one of $M$'s transition functions.

Comment: @Ariel Your last comment was supposed to be an answer.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ariel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/27055/ariel) explained [in the comments](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86947/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-following-problem#comment186459_86947):

"then $a$ indeed represents a valid computation of $M$ on $w$ since the Cook Levin reduction is parsimonious" - This has nothing to do with the reduction being parsimonious, this is a result of the specific construction of the reduction. Also, you don't have to appeal to Cook-Levin to encode computations of a Turing machine, there is no real reason to talk about assignments for boolean formulas in this context. You can simply say that $a$ is a description of $M$'s tape, state, and head location during some prefix of its computation.

Additionally, the input should consist of $M,w$ alone, you don't have any information about $M$'s running time from its encoding (how would you know if the machine actually runs in exponential time?). Now, the problem is trivially solvable in polynomial time by reading $a$ and checking that any configuration is reachable from its predecessor by one of $M$'s transition functions.

Comment: This answer is a copy of Ariel's comments word-for-word, in their entirety, without crediting the source.  It's great that you wrote an answer based on the comments you received; [that's great](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251/160917).  However, [posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [against our rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).  So, please always credit your sources.